# How to put cursor to end of line in bash

Tags: bash, terminal

When I write something in PS1 it puts cursor at begin of the line but I want to see it in the end after `$`

`\n` starts from new line works but it is not a way.

How to make it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TSQG.png]

Comment: What "something" did you write into PS1?

Comment: should be "hostname" taken here from http://bashrcgenerator.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you save your file with Unix-style newlines, that is, LF characters only.

Most likely the newlines in your file are CR+LF, and that CR (carriage return), invisible as you edit the file, becomes the last character of your prompt, moving the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: it helped, thanks @egmont